# How to sum strings of hours and minutes without the use of any date or time libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I should not use any date or time libraries!  Actually I was able to sum them as normal integers but I couldn't find how to sum them as hours and minutes so as an example "03:50" + "04:20" should be "08:10" but actually I got "7:70" because I still couldn't find valid approach. Any hint or approach is much appreciated. Thank you.

```
import re

def add_time(time, duration):

 
  elems1 = re.split(r"\s", time)
  elems2 = re.split(r":", elems1[0])
  elems2.append(elems1[1])
  elems3 = re.split(r":", duration)


  resH = eval(elems2[0]) + eval(elems3[0])
  resM = eval(elems2[1]) + eval(elems3[1])

  
  return f'{str(resH)}:{str(resM)} {elems2[2]}'


print(add_time("3:50 AM", "4:20"))
```

Actual output

```
7:70 AM
```

Desired output

```
08:10 AM
```

Comment: Why can't you use e.g. the `datetime` module?

Comment: coz I 'am asked to. Please read description.

Comment: I read the description: that's why I ask why you're unable to use the `datetime` module ..?

Comment: Please upvote if you find my question relevant. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it by yourself by using `%` to keep track of hours and minutes format, but keep in mind that the remainder of the minutes, if came across 60, should passed to the hours.

take a look in this implementation:

```
import re
import numpy as np
def add_time(time, duration):

 
    elems1 = re.split(r"\s", time)
    elems2 = re.split(r":", elems1[0])
    elems2.append(elems1[1])
    elems3 = re.split(r":", duration)

    remainder_from_minutes = int(np.floor((int(elems2[1]) + int(elems3[1]))/60))
    resH = (int(elems2[0]) + int(elems3[0]))%24 + remainder_from_minutes
    resM = (int(elems2[1]) + int(elems3[1]))%60
    am_or_pm = elems2[2] if int(resH/12)%2==0 else chr(145-ord(elems2[2][0])) + "M"
        return str(resH).rjust(2,"0") + ":" + str(resM).rjust(2,"0") + " " + str(am_or_pm)


print(add_time("3:50 AM", "8:50"))
print(add_time("3:20 PM", "8:50"))
```

output:

```
12:40 PM
12:10 AM
```

fixed AM/PM notation as well, with some ascii table tricks, in such way that also 12:40 AM and 03:50 PM will be acceptable

Comment: oh yes, how to deal with AM/PM will be veeeeeeeeeeeery appreciated!

Comment: Thank you very much! Well, I never used numpy before and I will training my self on it, anyway, oh yes, how to deal with AM/PM will be veeeeeeeeeeeery appreciated and great favor!  It's allowed to use 12 hours format: first 12 hours AM and the last 12 hours PM. thank you for your precious help.

Comment: oh this is kinda advanced for me, I am gonna spend the next hours studying and understanding your implementation. Thank you very much Levi.

Comment: there is an issue with leading zero like "03:30" , any solution to this annoying python bug?

Comment: if you mean that the hour whenever the hour is 1 digit not consist leading zero, so the last edit of mine will always pad the hour to 2 digits with leading "0"s, just by using `rjust` function of string. i that answer your modified question?

Comment: sorry i mean the error occurs when minutes are preceding by 0 like '3:03' but iam working on it now and gonna solve it soon. thanks.

Comment: use the same `rjust` for the minutes as well, re-edit also for it

Comment: Please upvote if you find my question relevant. Thanks.

Comment: Please upvote if you find my question relevant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should add just condition for handling when minutes is greater than 59 and when hour is greater than 12.

```
import re

def add_time(time, duration):


  elems1 = re.split(r"\s", time)
  elems2 = re.split(r":", elems1[0])
  elems2.append(elems1[1])
  elems3 = re.split(r":", duration)

  cf = 0
  resM = eval(elems2[1]) + eval(elems3[1])

  if (resM > 60):
    cf = 1
    resM = resM - 60
  resH = eval(elems2[0]) + eval(elems3[0]) + cf

  if(resH > 12):
    resH = resH - 12

  return f'{str(resH)}:{str(resM)} {elems2[2]}'
```

Comment: Please upvote if you find my question relevant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way to do this is to convert everything to minutes, sum them and convert them to hours + minutes back. This is good because this way you will be able to scale your system in future, for example, make it possible to add more than just two time values (which is not possible in one of the other answers). Because you are using Python which has built-in long arithmetic I don't see any disadvantages of this solution